# How to select and process the selected records from a list of displayed records in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php/mysql application in which I have a database broadly having the following fields:

- Employee No.
- Employee Name
- Year of Joining
- Location
- Job Profile

I am able to display the records using the SELECT statement with no problem.

Now, I want to be able to do the following and this is where I need your help/suggestion on how to achieve it:

1. Select a few records randomly (using a checkbox or any other method suggested here) from the list of records displayed.
2. Have a button saying "Processed" on the screen. When I click on the button, the  screen should refresh and the records selected in Step 1 above should be moved to another database and only the unchecked records should now be displayed.

Please let me know your suggestion on how to do the above.

Thanks
TS

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use the id of the record, to get the information of the particular record using another single select query, and also can update the record with the id of the record. (create an edit link and pass the id, on edit page get the information with the id and save it.)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. Is it possible to elaborate this with an example please?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php //your db connection and select query here ?>
<form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
    // loop starts here
   echo "<input type='checkbox' name='ids[]' value='".$row["id"]."' />";
    // loop ends here
?>
  <input type="submit" name="process" value="Processed"/>
</form>

This will create the checkboxes and on the process.php page
you can get the ids your need to process and can move your data
to other table/db where you want and after than redirect back to
to the page where your code is.
```